# My tabhost is not working

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am working with the tabhost with 2 tabs i am unable nothing in the tab activity,

This is the main class where i implemented the tab host

```
tabHost = getTabHost();
//*   TabHost Implementations*//*
tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
tabHost.setup();

TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("FirstTab");
TabSpec tab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("SecondTab");

// Set the Tab name and Activity
// that will be opened when particular Tab will be selected
tab1.setIndicator("Friends");
Intent tab1intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Friends_list_add.class);
tab1intent.putExtra("userid", userid);
System.out.println("tabHost------" + tab1intent);
tab1.setContent(tab1intent);

tab2.setIndicator("Invite Friends");
Intent tab2intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Friends_Invite_list.class);
tab2intent.putExtra("response", response);
System.out.println("tab2intent------" + tab2intent);
tab2.setContent(tab2intent);


//** Add the tabs  to the TabHost to display. *//*
tabHost.addTab(tab1);
tabHost.addTab(tab2);

tab = 1;
//set Windows tab as default (zero based)
tabHost.setCurrentTab(tab);
```

Through intent I am switching to another activity in that activity in onCreate

I have to view a layout as follows textview but it's not displaying anything

```
no_friends = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.nodata_found_friends);
```

I have referred all the website but still didn't get anything,
       Please help me, Thanks in advance

Comment: You should try this type of example.http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/android-tutorial-using-the-viewpager.html

Comment: post your stacktrace

Comment: i am not using fragment activity

Comment: @HariniPasupathy FYI TabActivity is deprecated . Beaware from this

Comment: what is mean"FYI TabActivity is deprecated " i am new in using this tabhost and using it in android studio

Comment: @HariniPasupathy check this http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/252fe66e-8288-4fed-b14d-06862cea8faf/TabHost%20Control%20in%20Android#.VUSqNN-jmb8

Comment: @HariniPasupathy Use Fragment Viewpager instead this . For more information please have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391478/the-type-tabactivity-is-deprecated-for-app-tab

Comment: i have added the warning also but its not working

Comment: This tab host is working in the eclipse but not working in the android studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way to make tabhost i m sure its work.

```js
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener,
  OnClickListener {

 private ImageView iv_Home;
 private ImageView iv_Chat;
 private ImageView iv_Post;
 private ImageView iv_Alert;
 private ImageView iv_More;
 private TabHost tabHost;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
  Casting();
 }

 private void Casting() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  iv_Home = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_Home);
  iv_Chat = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_Chat);
  iv_Post = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_Post);
  iv_Alert = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_Alert);
  iv_More = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_More);

  iv_Home.setOnClickListener(this);
  iv_Chat.setOnClickListener(this);
  iv_Post.setOnClickListener(this);
  iv_Alert.setOnClickListener(this);
  iv_More.setOnClickListener(this);

  tabHost = getTabHost();
  tabHost.setup();

  TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec;

  tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator("")
    .setContent(new Intent(this, CategoryActivity.class));
  tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

  tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator("")
    .setContent(new Intent().setClass(this, ChatActivity.class));
  tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

  tabSpec = tabHost
    .newTabSpec("Tab3")
    .setIndicator("")
    .setContent(
      new Intent().setClass(this, LoginActivity.class));
  tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

  tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab4").setIndicator("")
    .setContent(new Intent().setClass(this, AlertActivity.class));
  tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

  tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab5").setIndicator("")
    .setContent(new Intent().setClass(this, MoreActivity.class));
  tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

  tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
  tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
  setSelectedTabColor();

 }

 @SuppressWarnings("unused")
 @Override
 public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  int pos = this.tabHost.getCurrentTab();
  // this.mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);
  setSelectedTabColor();
 }

 // private static void AddTab(MainActivity activity, TabHost tabHost,
 // TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec) {
 // tabSpec.setContent(new CategoryTabFactory(activity));
 // tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
 // }

 private void setSelectedTabColor() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  switch (tabHost.getCurrentTab()) {
  case 0:
   Global.setActionbar(this, getActionBar(),
     getString(R.string.app_name));
   iv_Home.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_home_hover);
   iv_Chat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_chat);
   iv_Post.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_post);
   iv_Alert.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_alert);
   iv_More.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_more);
   break;
  case 1:
   Global.setActionbar(this, getActionBar(), getString(R.string.chat));
   iv_Home.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_home);
   iv_Chat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_chat_hover);
   iv_Post.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_post);
   iv_Alert.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_alert);
   iv_More.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_more);
   break;
  case 2:
   Global.setActionbar(this, getActionBar(),
     getString(R.string.post_product));
   iv_Home.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_home);
   iv_Chat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_chat);
   iv_Post.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_post_hover);
   iv_Alert.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_alert);
   iv_More.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_more);
   break;
  case 3:
   Global.setActionbar(this, getActionBar(), getString(R.string.alert));
   iv_Home.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_home);
   iv_Chat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_chat);
   iv_Post.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_post);
   iv_Alert.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_alert_hover);
   iv_More.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_more);
   break;
  case 4:
   Global.setActionbar(this, getActionBar(), getString(R.string.more));
   iv_Home.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_home);
   iv_Chat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_chat);
   iv_Post.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_post);
   iv_Alert.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_alert);
   iv_More.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_more_hover);
   break;
  default:
   break;
  }
 }

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  if (v == iv_Home) {
   tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
  } else if (v == iv_Chat) {
   tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
  } else if (v == iv_Post) {
   tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
  } else if (v == iv_Alert) {
   tabHost.setCurrentTab(3);
  } else if (v == iv_More) {
   tabHost.setCurrentTab(4);
  }
  setSelectedTabColor();
 }
}
```

Comment: how can i send the values between this tabs

Comment: what is the use of setSelectedTabColor() method here

Comment: its just i use to display different different tabs. I made that method see where i m use that

Comment: how can i implement your code in my activity i am not using the images,i am using only two tabs with two activity.

Comment: then remove image view and put two tabs. with ur tabs which u create in xml file

Answer (score 0):

First code put in xml File

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/title_back_color" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="6" />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.10"
            android:background="@color/popular_back_color"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:showDividers="none"
            android:tabStripEnabled="false" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

now in your main activity to put this code.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    OnTabChangeListener, OnPageChangeListener {

MyPageAdapter pageAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private TabHost mTabHost;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    // Tab Initialization
    initialiseTabHost();

    // Fragments and ViewPager Initialization
    List<Fragment> fragments = getFragments();
    pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(MainActivity.this);
}

// Method to add a TabHost
private static void AddTab(MainActivity activity, TabHost tabHost,
        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec) {
    tabSpec.setContent(new MyTabFactory(activity));
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
}

// Manages the Tab changes, synchronizing it with Pages
public void onTabChanged(String tag) {
    int pos = this.mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
    this.mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);

    setSelectedTabColor();
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
}

// Manages the Page changes, synchronizing it with Tabs
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    int pos = this.mViewPager.getCurrentItem();
    this.mTabHost.setCurrentTab(pos);
}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
}

@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
private void setSelectedTabColor() {
    for (int i = 0; i < mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {

        TextView tv = (TextView) mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                .findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

        mTabHost.getTabWidget()
                .getChildAt(i)
                .setBackgroundColor(
                        getResources().getColor(R.color.popular_back_color));
    }
    mTabHost.getTabWidget()
            .getChildAt(mTabHost.getCurrentTab())
            .setBackgroundColor(
                    getResources().getColor(R.color.app_yellow_color));
}

private List<Fragment> getFragments() {
    List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    // TODO Put here your Fragments
    // DealTab f1 = DealTab.newInstance();
    DealTab_New f1 = DealTab_New.newInstance();
    EventTab f2 = EventTab.newInstance();

    MyAccountFragment f3 = MyAccountFragment.newInstance();
    MessageFragment f4 = MessageFragment.newInstance();
    MoreFragment f5 = MoreFragment.newInstance();
    QrCodeFragment f6 = QrCodeFragment.newInstance();

    // fList.add(f1);
    fList.add(f1);
    fList.add(f2);
    fList.add(f3);
    fList.add(f4);
    fList.add(f5);
    fList.add(f6);

    return fList;
}

// Tabs Creation
@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
private void initialiseTabHost() {
    mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();

    // TODO Put here your Tabs
    MainActivity.AddTab(
            this,
            this.mTabHost,
            this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator(
                    "",
                    getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(
                            R.drawable.btn_deals)));

    MainActivity.AddTab(
            this,
            this.mTabHost,
            this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator(
                    "",
                    getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(
                            R.drawable.btn_event)));
    MainActivity.AddTab(
            this,
            this.mTabHost,
            this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator(
                    "",
                    getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(
                            R.drawable.btn_my_account)));
    MainActivity.AddTab(
            this,
            this.mTabHost,
            this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab4").setIndicator(
                    "",
                    getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(
                            R.drawable.btn_message)));
    MainActivity.AddTab(
            this,
            this.mTabHost,
            this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Tab5").setIndicator(
                    "",
                    getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(
                            R.drawable.btn_more)));

    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

    setSelectedTabColor();
}
```

its work proper way and i use this in my application.
Thanks & Regards.

Comment: what is the use of ViewPager in this

Comment: I am not using the fragment

Comment: ViewPager is swipe the page  and what  you are using?

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but i am not using the fragment i am using the activity only